# OpenGL ES Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1, fault addr 0x8 in tid 8367 (GLThread 3562)

Tags: android, opengl-es-2.0, gldrawarrays

I have a crash in my call to glDrawArrays when trying to render a .obj loaded using a library. I dont know what is happening since it is my first time using openGL ES. My guess was that the number of triangles was wrong and after trying glDrawArrays with 10 as parameter, I realised this might not be the problem.

The code of my renderer:

```
 private class RocketArrowRenderer implements GLSurfaceView.Renderer {
    private final int mBytesPerFloat = 4;
    private Context mContext;
    private FloatBuffer mVertices;
    private int mMVPMatrixHandle;
    private int mPositionHandle;
    private float[] mModelMatrix = new float[16];
    private int mColorHandle;
    private float[] mMVPMatrix = new float[16];
    private final int mStrideBytes = 3 * mBytesPerFloat;
    private final int mPositionOffset = 0;
    private final int mPositionDataSize = 3;
    private final int mColorOffset = 3;
    private final int mColorDataSize = 4;
    private float[] mViewMatrix = new float[16];
    final String vertexShader =
            "uniform mat4 u_MVPMatrix;      \n"     // A constant representing the combined model/view/projection matrix.

                    + "attribute vec4 a_Position;     \n"     // Per-vertex position information we will pass in.
                    + "uniform vec4 a_Color;        \n"     // Per-vertex color information we will pass in.

                    + "varying vec4 v_Color;          \n"     // This will be passed into the fragment shader.

                    + "void main()                    \n"     // The entry point for our vertex shader.
                    + "{                              \n"
                    + "   v_Color = a_Color;          \n"     // Pass the color through to the fragment shader.
                    // It will be interpolated across the triangle.
                    + "   gl_Position = u_MVPMatrix   \n"     // gl_Position is a special variable used to store the final position.
                    + "               * a_Position;   \n"     // Multiply the vertex by the matrix to get the final point in
                    + "}                              \n";    // normalized screen coordinates.

    final String fragmentShader =
            "precision mediump float;       \n"     // Set the default precision to medium. We don't need as high of a
                    // precision in the fragment shader.
                    + "varying vec4 v_Color;          \n"     // This is the color from the vertex shader interpolated across the
                    // triangle per fragment.
                    + "void main()                    \n"     // The entry point for our fragment shader.
                    + "{                              \n"
                    + "   gl_FragColor = v_Color;     \n"     // Pass the color directly through the pipeline.
                    + "}                              \n";

    final float eyeX = 0.0f;
    final float eyeY = 0.0f;
    final float eyeZ = 25.0f;

    final float lookX = 0.0f;
    final float lookY = 0.0f;
    final float lookZ = 0.0f;

    final float upX = 0.0f;
    final float upY = 1.0f;
    final float upZ = 0.0f;
    private boolean mObjLoaded = false;

    public RocketArrowRenderer(Context context)
    {
        mContext = context;
        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                Resources res = mContext.getResources();

                InputStream inputStream = res.openRawResource(R.raw.falcon_heavy_obj);

                Obj obj = null;
                try {
                    obj = ObjUtils.convertToRenderable(ObjReader.read(inputStream));
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                mVertices = ObjData.getVertices(obj);
                mObjLoaded = true;
            }
        }).start();



    }

    @Override
    public void onSurfaceCreated(GL10 glUnused, EGLConfig config) {
        GLES20.glClearColor(0.5f, 0.5f, 0.5f, 0.5f);

        Matrix.setLookAtM(mViewMatrix, 0, eyeX, eyeY, eyeZ, lookX, lookY, lookZ, upX, upY, upZ);
        int vertexShaderHandle = GLES20.glCreateShader(GLES20.GL_VERTEX_SHADER);

        if (vertexShaderHandle != 0)
        {
            GLES20.glShaderSource(vertexShaderHandle, vertexShader);
            GLES20.glCompileShader(vertexShaderHandle);
            final int[] compileStatus = new int[1];
            GLES20.glGetShaderiv(vertexShaderHandle, GLES20.GL_COMPILE_STATUS, compileStatus, 0);
            if (compileStatus[0] == 0)
            {
                GLES20.glDeleteShader(vertexShaderHandle);
                vertexShaderHandle = 0;
            }

        }

        if (vertexShaderHandle == 0)
        {
            throw new RuntimeException("Error creating vertex shader.");
        }

        // Load in the vertex shader.
        int fragmentShaderHandle = GLES20.glCreateShader(GLES20.GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER);
        if(fragmentShader != null){
            GLES20.glShaderSource(fragmentShaderHandle, fragmentShader);
            GLES20.glCompileShader(fragmentShaderHandle);
            final int[] compileStatus2 = new int[1];
            GLES20.glGetShaderiv(vertexShaderHandle, GLES20.GL_COMPILE_STATUS, compileStatus2, 0);
            if(compileStatus2[0] == 0){
                GLES20.glDeleteShader(fragmentShaderHandle);
                fragmentShaderHandle = 0;
            }
        }
        if(fragmentShader == null){
            throw new RuntimeException("Error creating fragment shader");
        }
        int programHandle = GLES20.glCreateProgram();

        if (programHandle != 0)
        {
            GLES20.glAttachShader(programHandle, vertexShaderHandle);

            GLES20.glAttachShader(programHandle, fragmentShaderHandle);
            GLES20.glBindAttribLocation(programHandle, 0, "a_Position");
            GLES20.glBindAttribLocation(programHandle, 1, "a_Color");
            GLES20.glLinkProgram(programHandle);
            final int[] linkStatus = new int[1];
            GLES20.glGetProgramiv(programHandle, GLES20.GL_LINK_STATUS, linkStatus, 0);
            if (linkStatus[0] == 0)
            {
                GLES20.glDeleteProgram(programHandle);
                programHandle = 0;
            }
        }

        if (programHandle == 0) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Error creating program.");
        }
        mMVPMatrixHandle = GLES20.glGetUniformLocation(programHandle, "u_MVPMatrix");
        mPositionHandle = GLES20.glGetAttribLocation(programHandle, "a_Position");
        mColorHandle = GLES20.glGetAttribLocation(programHandle, "a_Color");
        GLES20.glUseProgram(programHandle);

    }
    private float[] mProjectionMatrix = new float[16];

    @Override
    public void onSurfaceChanged(GL10 glUnused, int width, int height)
    {
        GLES20.glViewport(0, 0, width, height);
        final float ratio = (float) width / height;
        final float left = -ratio;
        final float right = ratio;
        final float bottom = -1.0f;
        final float top = 8.0f;
        final float near = 1.0f;
        final float far = 10.0f;

        Matrix.frustumM(mProjectionMatrix, 0, left, right, bottom, top, near, far);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDrawFrame(GL10 glUnused)
    {
        GLES20.glClear(GLES20.GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT | GLES20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
        Matrix.setIdentityM(mModelMatrix, 0);
        if(mObjLoaded){
                    draw();
        }
    }


    private void draw() {
        int numberOfTriangles = mVertices.position(0).remaining() / 3;
        //mVertices.position(mPositionOffset);
        GLES20.glVertexAttribPointer(mPositionHandle, mPositionDataSize, GLES20.GL_FLOAT, false,
                0, 0);
        GLES20.glEnableVertexAttribArray(mPositionHandle);
        //and later, in draw
        GLES20.glUniform4f(mColorHandle, 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f); //red!

        Matrix.multiplyMM(mMVPMatrix, 0, mViewMatrix, 0, mModelMatrix, 0);
        Matrix.multiplyMM(mMVPMatrix, 0, mProjectionMatrix, 0, mMVPMatrix, 0);

        GLES20.glUniformMatrix4fv(mMVPMatrixHandle, 1, false, mMVPMatrix, 0);
        GLES20.glDrawArrays(GLES20.GL_TRIANGLES, 0, numberOfTriangles);
    }
}
```

Comment: @Rabbid76 I created the code from a tutorial on internet. There was a context. And it was rendering a triangle. Then I tried to load my own 3D model and everything crashes .. I made some modifications and that's probably what causes the crash

Answer (score 0):

You need to call `GLES20.glEnableVertexAttribArray(mPositionHandle);` 
before using 
`GLES20.glVertexAttribPointer(mPositionHandle, mPositionDataSize, GLES20.GL_FLOAT, false,
                0, 0);`